# Why does the Steinstalz Talmud interpret this one sentence in contradiction to Rashi?

Tags: talmud-gemara, translation

A sentence [towards the bottom of Sanhedrin page 5b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.5b.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) speaks of kneading dough in a state of impurity.

> דתניא פעם אחת הלך רבי למקום אחד וראה בני אדם שמגבלין עיסותיהם בטומאה ...‏

In the English Koren edition, Rabbi Steinsaltz translates this as meaning the people were impure.

> As it is taught in a baraita: Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi once went to a certain place, and he saw people there kneading dough while **they were** in a state of ritual impurity ...

This reflects the [Hebrew Steinstalz edition](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.5b.6?lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=en):

> דתניא [שכן שנינו בברייתא]: פעם אחת הלך רבי למקום אחד, וראה בני אדם שמגבלין (לשים) עיסותיהם בטומאה, שלא היו מקפידים בטהרת **עצמם** בשעת לישה ...‏

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.5b.6?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en), by contrast, interprets this passage as saying that the *vessels the people used* were impure:

> בטומאה - לא הוו מקפידין לטהר **כליהם**:‏

> In a state of ritual impurity - They weren't careful to purify **their vessels**.

<sup>(Mi Yodeya community translation)</sup>

The Schottenstein Edition reflects Rashi's interpretation.  Why might Rabbi Steinsaltz have interpreted this ambiguous sentence in a way contradictory to Rashi (who is the most influential commentator)? Are there any Rishonim who support his interpretation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111544/discussion-on-question-by-yehuda-w-why-does-the-steinstalz-talmud-interpret-this).

Answer (score -2):

If he deliberately meant to differ from Rashi, he should have explained in a note, so it is probably an oversight. No translation is completely reliable, but the Steinsaltz version in particular has some notable detractors. Here is a long critique by R' Aharon Feldman shlit"a.

https://www.jstor.org/stable/23260930?seq=1

And see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Talmud:_The_Steinsaltz_Edition

Comment: I realize he just passed away and the timing of my answer is unfortunate, but so it goes.

Comment: The translation that Rabbi Feldman critiqued (in 1991) was not the Koren edition (2012) that the OP is quoting (though I haven't checked if this comment is also present in the original edition)

Comment: Did the Koren make significant changes to the text of the translation? If not, the reviews of the original are still relevant.